# What to do when the original question changes so drastically that all answers seem absurd?

Tags: discussion, editing

This question:

[How do I get this uneven airbrush effect similar to old art deco posters?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9481/3270)

Had the reference image changed by the user.

I feel the new image is so drastically different than the original posted image that it makes the answer seem ridiculously off-base now. Disregard that it happens to be my answer. I'm fine with it being removed. I don't feel if the original image is changed the answer should remain.

I do feel like the new image the user is referencing requires a **completely** different solution and, for this reason, deserves a new question. This allows users to find the original solution for that particular grain technique as well as any new solution for the new image technique.

Seems to me the user essentially asked "What RGB Values will give me a Sky Blue"

Got answers in the range of "R70, G141, B255"

Then the user changed the question to "What RGB values will give me Fire Orange"

Thus editing the question so that any solution is entirely different.

The user seems to feel there's no reason for another question. And heck, I was ready to simply copy his edits and post the new question myself. But then the user wouldn't be notified or responses.

Not sure how to handle the back and forth.

Comment: I think you handled things appropriately, however you could also have just added a line at the top of your answer saying "the reference image has since changed, but here was my answer for the original question" or something to that effect...